# Is it better to create a table when you have to use a derived column in many queries?

Tags: mysql

I have some queries to do and I'm ending up using too many subqueries. One of the subqueries is to find a derived value which comes from summing two columns. So I thought if I make this derived column a table it would reduce the number of subqueries.

Here's the reduced code:

```
   with temp as(
select user_id,games_id,sum(case when buy_in IS NULL then cash_out end)-sum(case when cash_out is NULL then buy_in end) as total
from game_history
group by games_id, user_id
)
  select count(*) as cnt
  from (select user_id,games_id, total,SUM(CASE WHEN total <0 THEN 1 END)  OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY games_id ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) as sumNo
    from temp
)a
 where total>0
 group by user_id,sumNo;
```

I have used a temporary table but still there's one subquery. So is it better if that column `total` should be a table, and if yes how could I do that?

Here's the code which im trying to change:

```
  select count(*) as count
  from(  select user_id,games_id,total, SUM(CASE WHEN total <0 THEN 1           END) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY games_id ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)  AS sumNo
   from(
   select user_id,games_id,sum(case when buy_in IS NULL then cash_out end)-sum(case when cash_out is NULL then buy_in end) as total
   from game_history
   group by games_id, user_id
   )a) b
   WHERE total>0
   GROUP BY user_id, sumNo;
```

I've read that it's better to use joins instead of subqueries but I don't know if that applies to my query which uses attributes from only one table.

[HERE'S THE TABLE STRUCTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j44Ut.png) and also because of all the NULL values would it be better if I created two tables one for buy_in and one for cash_out.

I'm using mysql 8.0.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the table structures as a [mcve]. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query for SQL related questions.

Comment: Do `buy_in` and `cash_out` ever have non zero values in the same row?

Comment: @knot22 one of them is always null, they can't have non zero values at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of language items to clarify -
The first code snippet uses a CTE (common table expression) called `temp` and a derived table.  The second code snippet uses 2 derived tables.

If the queries being written are in a script that is just used to examine the data, and will not be used in Production, it would be fine to create a temporary table at the top of the script for the logic that is currently in the derived table and write subsequent queries with joins to the temp table.

If the queries being written will be incorporated into Production, then a view could be created containing the logic that is currently in the derived table and used for joining by other queries.

Regarding the table structure -
One approach would be to modify the existing table a bit.  Add a column for `amount_type` and another for `amount` (or whatever column names make sense).  The `amount_type` column would be populated with values that represent either "buy in" or "cash out" and the `amount` column would hold the number.  Then the `buy_in` and `cash_out` columns in the existing table would be removed after the data was moved over to the new columns.  Here is a screen shot of what the modified table would look like with a couple rows of data:
[image]

This structure should also help to simplify the queries.

Comment: Thank you, I think views would help. And also since I have null values I thought in creatting two tables one which contains the buy_in column and another which contains the cash_out column. Would that be better for normalization?

Comment: Please see updated answer with info about the table structure.